# Turing machine that converts decimal to binary

Tags: turing-machines

I'm a beginner in Turing machine computation and want to design two TMs; one that converts decimal number to binary, and other one that converts binary to decimal.

Could anyone help me design these Turing machines? How can I start?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! Do you have any ideas? How would you write a program to do this?

Comment: By designing, do you mean a low level description of a TM? Or a high level description? If you want get a better understanding of TMs, i suggest to start with implementing simple "functions". Such as moving the input around, marking the left end of the tape with a special letter or adding 1 to a number represented in binary. Once you master this stuff, you can easily implement a conversion from unary to binary and vice versa via basic bit manipulations.  In words, you can do it by standard long division and multiplication techniques and then generalize the same ideas to decimal.

Comment: This is essentially a programming questions, so arguably off-topic here.

Comment: Can you program this in your favorite programming language? Use the same ideas to program a Turing machine.

Comment: There are many kinds of Turing machines. For example, how many tapes does your Turing machine have? How are the input and output encoded (e.g., LSD vs MSD)?

Answer (score 2):

You can play around and try your ideas with this [simulator](https://turingmachinesimulator.com).

Under examples, you can find decimal to binary converter. Furthermore, you can learn about TMs in tutorial section.

Comment: Hi @roctothorpe , thanks :-) . I saw the simulator that "Sandro Lovnički" recommended, but  I steel can't design anything.I'm a little confused,maybe I need to spend more time

Comment: Hi @Bader Abu Radi , I want to show it as automata. Like https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=st65cJH1QBc